Is dipole approximation valid for ground - Rydberg transition?
I was curious following the dynamic equations of atom-light interaction (e.g., Ch. 5 of Quantum Optics from Scully), that we assume dipole approximation where size of the atom, $r$, is very small compared to the wavelength of the light, $\lambda$, i.e., $r\ll \lambda$.
For a near-ground states this is reasonable since the average size of the atom $\langle r \rangle \approx n^2 a_0\sim 1\rm~ nm$ where $a_0$ is a Bohr radius, and the typical laser beam has a wavelength of $\sim 1~\mu\rm m$, but the size of Rydberg atom scales upto similar scale compared to the wavelength, $\sim 1~\mu\rm m$, for large $n$.
Now I am curious; considering the size of Rydberg atom, it seems reasonable to consider the higher order term of $e^{ikr}$ and consider multipole transitions beyond the E1 transitions, however, as far as I know, the transition of ground-Rydberg state is explained well without considering these effects. Why is it so? Is there any references showing higher order terms could be neglectible?
